# jQuery find input where radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    $().ready(function () {
        $(".div").find("input").each(function (index) {
            if($(this).attr("checked")==true){
                console.log("You have checked the"+index);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
    <input name="1" type="radio" >
    <input name="1" type="radio"  checked="checked" >
    <input name="1" type="radio" >
    <input name="1" type="radio" >
</div>
```

Why I cannot use "find" and "each" function to justify which the radio is checked?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value is `'checked'`, not `true`:

```
if ($(this).attr("checked") == 'checked') {
  console.log("You have checked the " + index);
}
```

Also note that you can make the index retrieval a one-liner using the `:checked` selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = $(".div").find("input:checked").index();

  console.log("You have checked the " + index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <input name="1" type="radio">
  <input name="1" type="radio" checked="checked">
  <input name="1" type="radio">
  <input name="1" type="radio">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("You have checked the " + $("input[name=1]:checked").index());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <input name="1" type="radio">
  <input name="1" type="radio" checked="checked">
  <input name="1" type="radio">
  <input name="1" type="radio">
</div>
```

No need to use `.each()` use selector [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

> Description: Matches all elements that are checked or selected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is whenever you perform `$(this).attr("checked")` it does NOT returns `true`, instead, it returns `checked` for the radio's that are checked and `undefined` for those which aren't checked.

```js
$().ready(function () {
        $("div").find("input").each(function (index) {
          if($(this).attr("checked")=="checked"){
                console.log("You have checked the "+index);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
    <input name="1" type="radio" >
    <input name="1" type="radio"  checked="checked" >
    <input name="1" type="radio" >
    <input name="1" type="radio" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find below fiddle.

```js
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code to find the value of the selected radio button:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="1">1</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="2">2</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="3">3</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="4">4</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="5">5</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){        
        alert($('input[name=q12_3]:checked').val());
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/ZkH8n/755/)